# how to get entire document in scrapy using hxs.select

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I've been at this for 12hrs and I'm hoping someone can give me a leg up.

Here is my code all I want is to get the anchor and url of every link on a page as it crawls along.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.utils.url import urljoin_rfc
from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url
from urlparse import urljoin

#from scrapy.item import Item
from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class HopitaloneSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'dmoz'
allowed_domains = ['domain.co.uk']
start_urls = [
    'http://www.domain.co.uk'
]

rules = (
    #Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow='>example\.org', )),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\w+$', )), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
)

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; WIndows NT 9.0; en-US))'

def parse_item(self, response):
    #self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)

    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    #print response.url
    sites = hxs.select('//html')
    #item = DmozItem()
    items = []

    for site in sites: 

                   item = DmozItem()
                   item['title'] = site.select('a/text()').extract()
                   item['link'] = site.select('a/@href').extract()

                   items.append(item)

    return items
```

What I'm doing wrong... my eyes hurt now.

Comment: Uh, the complete HTML resides in response.body... ;)

Comment: hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

Comment: Sorry for my silly question and I really appreciate your time. Its been a real steep learning curve for me. Could you spare me a second and adjust the code for me -- showing how I would get the anchor and link from any page. I'm trying to write a generic crawler and I only need these two elements.

Answer (score 3):

response.body should be what you want

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    #self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)

    body = response.body
    item = ....
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all links on a single page:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
  hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
  items = []
  links = hxs.select("//a")

  for link in links: 

                 item = DmozItem()
                 item['title'] = site.select('text()').extract()
                 item['link'] = site.select('@href').extract()

                 items.append(item)

return items
```

Comment: Hi, exactly what I was getting in my script above {'link': [], 'title': []}
blank titles and link when i run it from the command line